# Best way to add animation to custom view in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, custom-controls

I have a custom view where I've created a game. When a player earns some points, I'd like to add an animation of, say, "+500" bubbling up from an arbitrary x,y location relative to the custom view.

I'm thinking worst-case scenario, I could use different images for each screen size and animate them by having a thread change their location within my view's code in its onDraw, repeatedly calling invalidate. That just seems like I'm reinventing the wheel though.

How would one animate over a custom view in a better way, using something Android has that looks like its part of an existing view?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator). You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation). If you only want to animate text (like +500) then use a TextView and apply ValueAnimator on it. Something like this:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationY", 0,100f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.start();
```

You can get the y position of you custom view, and start the animation from there:

```
`ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationY",y,y-100f);`
```

Comment: Would I have to add this textView to my linearLayout with an addView call?

Answer (score 2):

Please find the following links if helpful,

You can make your `textView` animate using this tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-bubble-selection-animation-on-android-627044da4854

and you can use this library to create animating bubble background.

https://github.com/glomadrian/Grav

Comment: Looks good - but I'm not using OpenGL, I'm using Canvas.  Thanks!